# the android tensorflow demo build error with bazel command

Tags: android, tensorflow

when i run the tensorflow android demo.
i have installed the bazel for a long time to build the environment.
and then when all tool is done.then run the demo in Android Studio.
the gradle console show me this:

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1J7Zj.png)

and the error occured when the task of buildNative executed.
the full command line display in the gradle console:
    Starting process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel''. Working directory:      /Users/colarking/Workspace/tensorflow Command: /usr/local/bin/bazel build -c opt tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_native_libs --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=armeabi-v7a --verbose_failures --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain
Successfully started process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel''

Answer (score 1):

Did you build native libs with these commands?

```
CPU=armeabi-v7a
bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_native_libs --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=$CPU --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain

NATIVE_FOLDER=tensorflow/examples/android/libs/$CPU
mkdir -p $NATIVE_FOLDER
cp bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/android/libtensorflow_demo.so $NATIVE_FOLDER
```

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3444

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow cannot see the path to the NDK.  You need to update the WORKSPACE file in the  projects root folder with the NDK and sdk paths.  you also need to install the [correct NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) for your machine.  Follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md)